# Find the Equations of the straight line with the help of the given information.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Suppose two straight lines **3x+4y=5** & **4x-3y=15** cut each other at the point **A**. Take 2 points **B** & **C** on those 2 lines, such that **AB=AC**. If line **BC** passes through the point **(1,2)**, then find the possible equations of the straight line **BC**.

The given equations are **perpendicular** to each other & given that **AB=AC**. But I am unable to use the given information to find the solution.

Please help

**Thank you**

Comment: I really think you would benefit from trying to draw a picture first. Plot your two lines and determine what A is, then draw out two points on their respective lines so that that length is equal, and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean AB=AC instead AB=BC

1) It is not difficult to check that line *ax+by+c=0* is ortogonal to vector *(a,b)*.

2) Target lines are parallel to one of the two bisectrix of the given lines intersection angle.

3) Since we have *3x+4y=5* & *4x-3y=15* equations, then *n<sub>1</sub>=(3,4)* and *n<sub>2</sub>=(4,-3)* - ortogonal vectors with same length 5. So one of the bisectrix vector equal *n1+n2 = (7,1)*, second is ortogonal to this (-1,7).

4) So answer is two family of lines: *7x+y+c=0* and *-x+7y+c=0*

Answer (score 0):

Well, $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle since $AB=BC$. Still it also has a right angle in $A$. This is impossible... There is no such points $B$ and $C$ such that $AB = BC$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry.I have edited the incorrect question.